# Unable to inject EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, exception, ejb, bean-validation

I am not able to inject `EJBTransactionRolledbackException`. I want to catch `ConstraintViolationException`. So first I need catch `EJBTransactionRolledbackException` then I can propagate to `ConstraintViolationException` exception using `getCause()`.
How to inject it?

Below is my code.

```
 @ControllerAdvice
 public class RestExceptionProcessor extends            ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
// Here I am not able to inject EJBTransactionRolledbackException.
@ExceptionHandler({EJBTransactionRolledbackException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleUniqueKeyViolation(EJBTransactionRolledbackException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    Throwable t = ex.getCause();

    if(t != null &(t instanceof RollbackException)){

        if(t != null &(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
            return handleConstraintViolation((ConstraintViolationException) ex.getCause(), headers, status, request);
        }

        return handleConstraintViolation((RollbackException) ex.getCause(), headers, status, request);
    }

    String error = ex.getLocalizedMessage() + " " + ex.getMessage();
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}

@ExceptionHandler({RollbackException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(RollbackException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    String error = ex.getLocalizedMessage() + " " + ex.getMessage();
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}

@ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class})
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
        errors.add(violation.getRootBeanClass().getName() + " " + 
          violation.getPropertyPath() + ": " + violation.getMessage());
    }
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), error);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
    }
}
```

And my ApiErrors class is like below:

```
public class ApiError {

private HttpStatus status;
private String message;
private List<String> errors;

public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, List<String> errors) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.errors = errors;
}

public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, String error) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.errors = Arrays.asList(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps if you post some actual code?!

Comment: @BillyFrost - I have added code.

Comment: @RajKumar, does `@ExceptionHandler` belongs to spring?? If so, don't you think that the question should be marked with a spring tag ??